# Como não selecionar um determinado elemento do form?

Tags: jquery

Olá, eu gostaria que meu form não selecionasse o CAMPO_VALOR, mas mesmo usando o .not() ele ainda retorna um form com o CAMPO_VALOR.

```
var $form = $("#frmParcelas");
var formSemCampoValor = $form.not('#CAMPO_VALOR');
console.log(formSemCampoValor);
```

Agradeço desde de já pela ajuda.

Comment: Setar o atributo disabled no input campo_valor não resolve? disabled='disabled'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, espero que o exemplo abaixo lhe ajude, abraços.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="frmParcelas">
    <input type="text" value="oi" id="oi"/>
    <input type="text" value="oie" id="oie"/>
    <input type="text" value="" id="deuruim"/>
</form>

    <script>
        var $form = $("#frmParcelas");
        var formSemCampoValor = $('input:not([value]),input[value=""]').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```